# According to Sunni belief, would 'Ali is the Wali' statement added to adhan and ikamah invalidate the salah?

Tags: shia-sunni, bidah, adhan

The closest masjid to my residence is Shia.  I have been going there for convenience even though I was raised as a Hanafi Sunni.

Overall, as the congregational salah is not that much different than the Sunni salah.  They don't fold their hands during standing, and slight differences in dua.  However, they supplicate the adhan and ikamah with something that sounds like 'Ali is the Wali of Allah' after the standard 'Muhammed Al Rasul ulah'.
I understand that this means Ali is the governor or administrator of Allah.

Would Sunni Islam have an issue with this as a Bidaa?  Would it risk the acceptance of the Salah?

Comment: FWIW the Shias consider that be an **optional** part of adhan. The reasoning is that Ali was cursed by some Muslims and in order to honor him the scholar decided to add this as an **optional** part. To Shias the azan in it's original form doesn't have that part. That being said as a Shia I participate in Sunni prayers where the iqama is different. I'm not sure if you're sect allows you to do such.

Comment: To me this is harmless and shouldn't matter.  There is nothing in the Quran on adhan and ikamah, we have to depend on hadith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, a Zaydi Shia is different from an Imami Shia who is different from an Ismaili Shia. And there are differences even among individuals.

Depending on the Aqa'id of the imam, he may be considered a Kafir in Sunni Islam. If this is so then prayer behind him is invalid.

I don't think that Azan effect validity of the prayer, though you may want to avoid it as what is being implied by "Ali is the Wali" is that Abu Bakr, Umar and Uthman are Ghasib (usurpers).